# Count unique elements in list

Tags: list, dart

For example the result for

```
mylist = [1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 4]
```

I want to

```
a = [1,4,0]
b = [2,3,1]
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Come with the code and we can help you with the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
  final mylist = [1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 4];

  final result = mylist
      .fold(<int, int>{}, (Map<int, int> map, item) => map..update(item, (count) => count + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1));

  print(result.keys.toList());
  print(result.values.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final mylist = [1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 4];
  var counter = Map<int, int>.fromEntries(mylist.toSet().map<MapEntry<int, int>>((k) => MapEntry(k, mylist.where((e) => e == k).length)));
  print(counter.keys);
  print(counter.values);
}
```

Comment: Your option works, but big-O-wise it is  O(n*n), while solution I suggested is O(n) ;)

Comment: In fact it is `O(2.5N)`, tested with millions of data.