# How to count string in an List with Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an list of string in List. But I want to count it and display it in the text. How can I achieve that?

```
         StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot?>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("groups")
                      .doc(groupId)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                   //Get a snapShot
                    var countRoom = snapshot.data?['room'];
                    //Display a counted room
                    return Text(countRoom)
                   )
                 }
```

[image]

Comment: Fyi...You need to assign this `FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("groups")
                      .doc(groupId)
                      .snapshots(),` to a variable in initState and then use the variable as the stream: value.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to count it (the list)

If I correctly understand your question, you need to use the [`length`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180360/dart-core/List/length.html) property as follows:

```
var countRoom = snapshot.data?['room'];
var countRoomLength = countRoom.length;
```

---

If you want to count the unique elements in the List, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492956/3371862).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `sum` of the string in your list you can do this:

```
var rooms = snapshot.data?['room'];
int countRoom = rooms.fold(0, (int previousValue, element) => previousValue + int.parse(element));

return Text("$countRoom")//show 2
```

Comment: It says `The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`